# weighted bayes theorem

Tags: naive-bayes, bayes

I am using a simple implementation of Bayes theorem to find the discrete probability distribution of proportion of wins.

```
naiveBayes <- function(theta,prior,win=T)
    {
      ifelse(win==T,likelihood <- theta,likelihood <- 1-theta)
      constant <- sum(prior * likelihood)
      posterior <- (prior * likelihood) / constant
      posterior
    }
```

A win being `True` or `FALSE` gives a posterior which I will use a prior for the second computation and so on.

> *Question*: How to give more **weight** to recent event? Say, the new event is a loss (`win=F`), I would like it to have higher influence than what the bayes theorem provides.